# Flutter project won't compile after android dependencies change

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The issue started when I updated to the latest API 28. I read that the dependencies  from **com.*** moved to **androidx**. I tried different approaches to resolve the issue, but still I have not managed to make it compile.

My dependency structure

```
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1' 
}
```

The thing is that every time when I try to build it the error changes. Sometimes is

> Android dependency 'androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout' has
>   different version for the compile (1.0.0-rc01) and runtime (1.0.0)
>   classpath. -- **I do not have such lib in my dependency structure.**

others.. something with Dex conflicts so I tried setting  **multiDexEnabled true** at build.grandle and

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true at grandle.properties
```

I tried also the to upgrade and downgrade the **compileSdkVersion**...

```
previous

compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27

current

compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28
```

Moreover, I saw the migrate tutorial from google. Still, by using Flutter I do not have any of these libs in my structure (at least I did not put any of these at the dependencies-- maybe they fetched under the hound at compile time).

This thing drives me crazy for past few days.

Any insights would be really helpful. Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to my own post. The issue was one of the dependencies,especially, the  **fluttertoast**. There was some conflict with the new android repository. So, for now, I downgrade to 2.2.3 and it is working. :-)

Comment: Did you check https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_core#-changelog-tab- (related to other plugins as well). There was a problem with plugin versions not being incremented enough to indicate breaking changes. See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27128#issuecomment-458351250 and previous discussions. Also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27106

Comment: Yes, I did that... I just wanted to work, because it took me 2 days to identify the issue.. I will deal with new AndroidX dependencies on a later day.